# Magit : how to see pre-commit hooks before editing commit log?

Tags: git, emacs, magit

With **git** on the command line, you see the result of your pre-commit hooks before entering the commit's log message. If your pre-commit hook makes the commit fail, you are warnt and don't write anything.

But with **magit**, you are asked to enter your log comment and *then* it evaluates your hook, and if it fails *you don't see why*. You just read :

`git exited abnormally with code 1.`
I understand this is normal because it is when you are finished editing the log message that magit runs the git command.

So, how would you make magit to **evaluate your hook before asking for the log** ?
How can you make magit display the result of the hook ?

And a related question would be, how do you give arguments to you pre-commit hook in order to run it for the stashed files only, instead of all the files in the repository ?

I use pre-commit hooks mainly to check if I didn't forget debugging stuff, like a remaining 'ipdb', and some personal traces.

Thanks !

Comment: You might want to report the issue to magit. It seems to be a feature that is not present in magit but that could be useful.

Comment: Issue created at https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/449

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've wrote code for running the hook before opening the log-message buffer:

https://github.com/vanicat/magit/commit/87ec17c46b156c8508a47aa6c9ba982ef8a61b4c

You could test it, it miss the possibility to ignore the hook, and don't run others hook than pre-commit for now.

Answer (score 2):

After git failed when called by magit, you should be able to see why by using `$`

For evaluating pre-commit hook, there is nothing for now in magit.
You could try to put something in `magit-log-edit-mode-hook` for this:

```
(add-hook 'magit-log-edit-mode-hook
          '(lambda ()
                (shell-command "shell command to run git's hook")))
```

Of course, the shell command is lacking here...

For the related question in your pre-commit you will need to use git to know file that will be commited. Something like

```
git diff --name-only --cached
```

Comment: Thanks, the `--cached` option is perfect, but I couldn't do my trick with the hook. Using `$` is useful too.

Comment: For the hook, you could just run (shell-command "./.git/hooks/pre-commit")