# check if my commit has 'import pdb' in emacs/git?

Tags: python, git, emacs

I commit `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` quite often.

Is there a convenient way of preventing me doing it?

I use emacs/git (magit).

Comment: Good example of how to do this.  Almost the same use case, but with a ruby app.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20278573/git-pre-commit-hook

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11560336/magit-how-to-see-pre-commit-hooks-before-editing-commit-log and implementation of hooks in Magit: https://github.com/vanicat/magit/commit/87ec17c46b156c8508a47aa6c9ba982ef8a61b4c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For completeness, here's how to examine the contents of the version in the index, building off [eugene's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21298995/1256452) and with a few more changes (not tested as a complete hook, but should work):

```
#!/bin/sh

has_import=false
git diff --cached --no-renames --name-status --diff-filter=AM |
  while read st file; do
    case "$file" in
    *.py)
        if git show ":$file" |
          grep -E "^[^#]*\bimport[[:space:]]+pdb\b"; then
            echo "$file: has import pdb"
            exit 1
        fi;;
    esac
done || has_import=true

if $has_import; then
    exit 1
fi
```

The most important bit of change is the `git show ":$file"` trick, which uses `git show` to extract the staged version from the index.

I also:

- added `--no-renames` to make renamed files show up as `A`dded (dealing with `R` is harder, might as well just treat them as new);
- removed `C` as it would fail if it triggered (because the "other" file name is also printed, just as for `R`enames, but I think it will not trigger here anyway);
- removed some bash-specific syntax by using `case`; and
- beefed up the grep expression a bit (it's still not perfect, you could do `from pdb import ...`, or more likely, something like `import collections, pdb`, which it would not catch; but now it handles multiple spaces after `import`, and avoids false hits on, e.g., `import pdbase`).
- per [Matthieu Moy's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21298044/check-if-my-commit-has-import-pdb-in-emacs-git/21305090?noredirect=1#comment48059756_21305090), beefed up the shell fragment to set a `has_import` variable you can use later.  (If you don't intend to use anything later you can eliminate the variable and use `exit 1` there directly, as he suggested.)

(This still has at least one minor flaw: the extracted file-contents do not have any smudge filters applied.  But if your smudge and clean filters add and remove `import` lines, I suspect there's nothing a pre-commit hook can to do help you. :-) )

Comment: There's something fragile about this code: you're running "exit 1" on the right-hand side of a pipe, hence in a subshell. As a result, this "exit 1" won't quite the whole shell, but only the subshell. If you add anything after the last line, then the line will still be executed (and the return status of the subshell may be ignored). I'dd add a `|| exit 1` after the `done` keyword.

Comment: @MatthieuMoy: good point, modified the example (slightly differently in case the user wants to go on to do other checks even in the case of detecting an import).

Comment: fyi: the issue actually occured http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29969093/exit-1-in-pre-commit-doesnt-abort-git-commit/29972489#29972489

Answer (score 1):

You can create .git/hooks/pre-commit

```
#!/bin/bash

git diff --cached --name-status --diff-filter=ACM | while read st file; do
    if [[ "$file" =~ .py$ ]] && grep "^[^#]*import pdb" "$file"; then
        echo "$file: has import pdb"
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

I just made it up. not sure if it's good enough for general use but works for me.

Thanks David

Comment: Not perfect (the grep checks the working directory version of the file, while the `git diff --cached` more properly looks at the staged, to-be-committed version) but will work as long as you don't let the staged and to-be-committed versions diverge.

Answer (score 0):

`python3 -m pip install pre-commit` (or use pipx)

`cd my_repo`

Create a file called `.pre-commit-config.yaml` with the following contents

```
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    rev: v4.0.1
    hooks:
    -   id: debug-statements
```

Run `pre-commit install`

The next time you run `git commit` it will fail with

```
(random) mark@DESKTOP:~/pytest-bdd$ git commit -am "Adding breakpoint"
[INFO] Initializing environment for https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks.
[INFO] Installing environment for https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks.
[INFO] Once installed this environment will be reused.
[INFO] This may take a few minutes...
Debug Statements (Python)................................................Failed
- hook id: debug-statements
- exit code: 1

setup.py:2:0 - pdb imported
```

And it will not allow you to commit until
`breakpoint()` or `import pdb` is removed from the commit.

Note: if you just remove `import pdb` but not `pdb.set_trace()` e.g if you're in a rush and forget, it wont complain - but instead you now have introduced a syntax error.

See https://pre-commit.com for more information

See https://pre-commit.com/hooks.html for more hooks