# Does GIT cache pre-commit hooks

Tags: git, githooks, pre-commit, gjslint

Due to gJSLint spewing out errors because of missing member documentation.  We updated our  pre-commit hook tasked with linting JavaScript.  The edit included gJSLint rule 220 (ignore missing member documentation).  However when performing a commit GIT still complains that the JavaScript is invalid.  Running the gJSLint on its own produces no errors.

> gjslint --strict --disable=5,6,110,220 app/pits/modules/api.js

We have removed the staged files and then added them back to staging with no luck.

Does GIT cache pre-commit hooks?

**Pre-Commit Hook**

```sh
#!/bin/sh

files=$(git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM | grep ".js$") if [ "$files" = "" ]; then 
    exit 0  fi

pass=true

echo "\nValidating JavaScript:\n"

for file in ${files}; do
    result=$(gjslint --strict --disable=5,6,110,220 ${file} | grep "${file} is OK")
    if [ "$result" != "" ]; then
        echo "\t\033[32mJSLint Passed: ${file}\033[0m"
    else
        echo "\t\033[31mJSLint Failed: ${file}\033[0m"
        pass=false
    fi done

echo "\nJavaScript validation complete\n"

if ! $pass; then
    echo "\033[41mCOMMIT FAILED:\033[0m Your commit contains files that should pass JSLint but do not. Please fix the JSLint errors and try again.\n          try: gjslint --strict --disable=5,6,110,220 file.js\n"
    exit 1 else
    echo "\033[42mCOMMIT SUCCEEDED\033[0m\n" fi
```

**Result of git commit -m"...."**

> Validating JavaScript:
>
> JSLint Failed: app/pits/modules/api.js
>
> JSLint Failed: app/pits/modules/State.js
>
> JSLint Failed: app/pits/modules/table.js
>
> JavaScript validation complete
>
> COMMIT FAILED: Your commit contains files that should pass JSLint but
>
> ```
>               do not. Please fix the JSLint errors and try again.
>
>               try: gjslint --strict --disable=5,6,110,220 file.js
> ```

**Environment**

git       version 1.8.1.2

gjslint   version  2.3.13

lubuntu   version   13.04

Comment: The way you check for `gjslint` errors seems hacky. Can't you just check the return value instead of grepping the output? You might want to print the output as well to do some debugging.

Comment: Agreed, this would be a valuable improvement.

Comment: The answer to the subject-question is "no"; but your pre-commit hook contains various minor sins, aside from the [issue noted by pmr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21335220/does-git-cache-pre-commit-hooks#comment32162779_21335220).  See [check if my commit has 'import pdb' in emacs/git?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21298044/1256452) for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue had nothing to do with GIT and was caused by a poorly written pre-commit hook.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

files=$(git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM | grep ".js$")
if [ "$files" = "" ]; then
    exit 0
fi

pass=true

echo "\nValidating JavaScript:\n"

for file in ${files}; do
    eval "gjslint --strict --disable=5,6,110,220 ${file}"

    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "\t\033[32mJSLint Passed: ${file}\033[0m"
    else
        echo "\t\033[31mJSLint Failed: ${file}\033[0m"
        pass=false
    fi
done

echo "\nJavaScript validation complete\n"

if ! $pass; then
    echo "\033[41mCOMMIT FAILED:\033[0m Your commit contains files that should pass JSLint but do not. Please fix the JSLint errors and try again.\n          try: gjslint --strict --disable=5,6,110,220 file.js\n"
    exit 1
else
    echo "\033[42mCOMMIT SUCCEEDED\033[0m\n"
fi
```